Why should the kippah under the hat be visible (chareidi "dress code")?
It is customary in many chareidi communities to push the kippah out from under the hat so that it should be visible. (I personally like this custom very much since it gives me pride of my Torah identity in the galus.)
But is there any meaning or discussion anywhere in the rabbinic literature about this custom? Earliest when?

It could just be functional to ensure both the hat and yamulke stay firmly in place...

If it’s Shabbat and you don’t have an eruv, wearing one hat completely covered by another could be a problem

What's your source for this being a requirement rather than just a function of where both go on the head?

I think I've seen it discouraged because it's prideful.

@JoelK, I have a cousin who, when he liven in an area without an 'eruv, would leave a kippah at home and one in schul and, when he took off his hat (eg. to put on his tallis), would slide the kippah on so that his head remained covered. This kind of move appears to be common among hat-wearing Jews of a certain generation, though it's not really seen as much among younger folks

@NoachMiFrankfurt Some people do that throughout the week.

@JoelK very interesting! Could you refer any sources please about this?

@shmosel If you could find this source about "prideful", I would be very grateful!

@Binyomin See Machatzit HaShekel 301:49. It ends up becoming a little bit circular, and depends on whether it's normal to wear two hats in this way

@NoachMiFrankfurt People not wearing a hat + yarmulka outside on shabbat probably stems from the concern that the hat will blow off in the wind and one may come to pick it up and carry it (since his head his anyway covered by his yarmulka). See e.g. MB 301:153
